# Do I have to send files to a server using FormData() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, upload

I want to upload an image from the client-side and send it to a server in React. I've searched a bit and found that most tutorials/guides upload the image using a 'file' type input, then append it to a FormData object to send to the server.

Do I need to create the formData object or can I send the same way I would use just text/numbers? Would it work with a regular object like this:

```
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
    
      const onFileChange = (e: any) => {
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
        console.log(e.target.files[0]);
      };
    
        let newTodo = {
          title:'New Todo',
          description: 'A new task'
          todo_pic: selectedFile,
        };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what the backend program expects, **base-64 encoded blob** or **FormData**, what you have to do is appending files to formData or pass `form` event as initial parameter to that, here is a sample code:

```
function BlahBlah() {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(undefined);

  const handleOnChangeFile = (event) => {
    const imgFile = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("loadend", (val) => {
      setImage({
        file: imgFile,
        blob: val.srcElement.result
      });
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (image) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("IMAGE", image.file);

      console.log("FormData:", formData.get("IMAGE"));
      console.log("base-64 encoded blob:", image.blob);

      //here you can use XHR/Axios to upload image, e.g:
      /*
        axios.post("/file-uploader", (formData OR image.blob));
      */
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>take a look into console!</h1>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleOnChangeFile} />
      <button disabled={image ? false : true} onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-lab-n791v?file=/src/labPages/Experiments/test_files/3/index.jsx)